# How do I pronounce the possessive form of 'case'?

Tags: pronunciation, possessives

Is it "The **case'** closure" or "The **case's** closure"? How exactly do I pronounce it?

Comment: Full sentence, please.

Comment: Is it "The case' closure" and "The case's closure"?

Comment: There's no reason to ask for a full sentence here.  The answer would be the same regardless.

Comment: By the way, I tried to write a very general ("canonical"?) answer here, so ideally we can either close other questions about the pronunciation of the possessive suffix as a duplicate of this one, or we can at least use this answer as a reference.  I've been meaning to write this for a while, since we've gotten other questions like this one, but we didn't really have a good general answer to them.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The possessive suffix has three pronunciations.  Which one you use depends mainly on what the last sound is:

- /ɪz/, following sibilants (the six sounds /s/, /z/, /ʃ/, /tʃ/, /dʒ/, and /ʒ/)
- /z/, following voiced sounds other than sibilants (including vowels)
- /s/, following voiceless sounds other than sibilants

You might have noticed that these rules are exactly the same as [the rules for pronouncing the regular plural suffix *-(e)s*](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/18382/230).  But the possessive suffix is a little more complicated, because **sometimes it isn't pronounced at all**.

- When it *is* pronounced, it's typically written `'s`.
- When it's *not* pronounced, it's typically written `'`.

So how do we know when to pronounce it?

If the word ends in a sibilant and falls into one of the following categories, **the possessive suffix is not pronounced**, and is therefore written with just an apostrophe:

1. Regular plurals:

   > *boys'*　/bɔɪz/
   >   *cats'*　/kæts/

   In these examples, the /z/ and /s/ are already there as part of the plural suffix *-e(s)*, so we don't have to add another (and indeed shouldn't).
2. Irregular plurals where the plural affix itself is regular (for example *leaf*, where the base changes to *leave*, but the plural affix is regularly pronounced /z/):

   > *leaves'*　/liːvz/
   >   *knives'*　/naɪvz/
3. In certain fixed expressions:

   > *for goodness' sake*
   >   *for conscience' sake*
4. In Greek names of more than one syllable:

   > *Socrates'*
   >   *Xerxes'*
   >   *Euripides'*

One more rule: If a name ends in a /z/ sound, it may or may not be pronounced:

> *Dickens's*　OR　*Dickens'*
>   *Jones's*　　OR　*Jones'*
>   *Burns's*　　OR　*Burns'*

But although both versions work, people tend to *say* the former and *write* the latter more often.

---

Your example is the word *case*, pronounced /keɪs/.  It ends with an /s/ sound, which is a sibilant, one of the six sounds listed at the top of this answer.  That means we write the possessive `'s` and we pronounce it /ɪz/, making the possessive form *case's* /keɪsɪz/.

---

For more information, see *A Comprehensive Grammar of the English Language*, p.320.  Most of my examples and rules are drawn from this book.  Additional discussion can be found in *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language*, p.1595.  (Please note that the *possessive* form is often called the *genitive* form in linguistics, and technical references may use that term instead.)