# the possessive plural of a French family name ending in x

Tags: plural-forms, names

what is the possessive plural of the French name Rioux, in an English text?

Is it the Riouxes' house

or the Riouxs' house?

Comment: I would go by English pronunciation rules. How would you pronounce this in English terms? But honestly you should ask this on [French Language SE](http://french.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: It would be off-topic there because it's about English, not French.

Comment: http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/74312/230

Answer (score 2):

You would form it based on the plural form of *Rioux,* so the first step is finding what that is.

According to the *Daily Writing Tips* article "[Plurals of Proper Names](http://www.dailywritingtips.com/plurals-of-proper-names/)" by Mark Nichol,

> The plural forms of names ending in unpronounced -s or -x are
>   identical to the singular form: “The era between the third and seventh
>   Louis,” “The two Lacroix could not have been any different,” though “.
>   . . Louis III and Louis VII” and “The two Lacroix brothers . . .”
>   would be better.

So the plural of *Rioux* would just be *Rioux.*

To form the possessive of a plural noun that ends in the letter *x,* you just add an apostrophe.

So the possessive of the plural would be spelled *Rioux',* and your example would be "the Rioux' house."

However, this is not totally certain, because apparently Wikipedia said something different; see this answer from Reg Dwight on ELU: [What is the correct possessive form of names ending in “x”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/4152/77227)

Answer (score 0):

In English the normal solution is *periphrasis*--which simply means you will avoid the problem by re-wording the statement.

Periphrasis isn't limited to English.  It is a general strategy for avoiding uncertain declination or conjugation.  It uses a different construction (in this case, something like "the house of the Rioux family") to sidestep the difficulty.

The alternative is not going to be something that will pass for correct English.